# Spring Boot Aspectj test with MockMvc

Tags: java, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-boot-test

I have a Spring boot code with Aspectj. This code has written with basic MVC architecture. Then I just try to test it with MockMVC. But when I try to test it, Aspectj doesn't interrupted. Is there a special configuration about Aspectj?

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("user/{userId}/todo-list")
public ResponseEntity<?> getWaitingItems(@RequestUser CurrentUser currentUser){
    ...handle it with service method.
}
```

Aspect:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* *(.., @RequestUser (*), ..))")
void annotatedMethod()
{
}

@Before("annotatedMethod() && @annotation(requestUser)")
public void adviseAnnotatedMethods(JoinPoint joinPoint, RequestUser requestUser)
{
    ...
}
```

Test:

```
@WebMvcTest(value = {Controller.class, Aspect.class})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Controller.class, Aspect.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ControllerTest
{
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private Controller controller;

    @MockBean
    private Service service;

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getWaitingItems() throws Exception
    {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/user/{userId}/todo-list", 1L))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring [@WebMvcTest](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/) will only instantiate web layer and it will not load complete application context

> **However, in this test, Spring Boot instantiates only the web layer rather than the whole context.**

In order to test Aspectj you need to load whole application context using @SpringBootTest annotation

> **The @SpringBootTest annotation tells Spring Boot to look for a main configuration class (one with @SpringBootApplication, for instance) and use that to start a Spring application context**

So annotate the test using `@SpringBootTest` annotation

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ControllerTest {

   @Autowired
   private MockMvc mockMvc;

   @Autowired
   private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

   @Autowired
   private Controller controller;

   @Before
   public void setUp() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
            .build();
      }

    @Test
    public void getWaitingItems() throws Exception  {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/user/{userId}/todo-list", 1L))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 13):

There is no need for a `@SpringBootTest` if you wanna do integration tests of specific controller (web layer) + your custom Aspect logic (AOP layer).

Try something like this

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = {AnyController.class})
@Import({AopAutoConfiguration.class, ExceptionAspect.class})
public class ErrorControllerAdviceTest {
```

- AnyController.class: controller under test
- AopAutoConfiguration.class: Spring Boot auto-configuration of AOP
- ExceptionAspect.class: class containing AOP logic

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ExceptionAspect {}
```

Tested with Spring Boot 2.2.1.RELEASE and JUNIT5.
I am unsure, if my solution is technically the same like @Deadpool answers

Comment: Thank you. Lower execution time vs instantiating the whole application context, especially when you have to test tens of endpoints from different controllers.

Comment: IMHO, this should be voted as it is the better answer.

Comment: Does not work on SpringBoot 2.7.1 and JUnit5

Comment: I have tried all kinds of other comments, and this is the only one that worked in a non-integration manner.